# IBM DB2 v9.5におけるCLI接続エラー

Tags: php, database

タイトルに有る通りDB2(v9.5)にPHP5.6から接続したいのですがエラーが出て接続できません。

**エラー内容**

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code page "819" to the target code page "UNKNOWN" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=57017 SQLCODE=-332
```

**接続元情報**

- Linux Centos6.7
- PHP 5.6
- ibm_db2 1.9.7

**接続先情報**

- WindowsServer　2003 R2
- IBM DB2 v9.5

対象DBのコードセットはIBM-943になっていてUnicodeで構築されていた他DBに対してはアクセスできたので接続元環境に関しては大丈夫だと思ってます。

エラーの「UNKNOWN」の部分を設定できればどうにかなると思ってたのですがWindowsの環境変数にDB2CODEPAGEをセットしたり下記コマンドを叩いても表示は変わりませんでした。

```
db2set DB2CODEPAGE=943
```

解決方法をご存じの方はよければご協力お願いします。

Comment: 以下のgistでも似たような検証結果がありました。https://gist.github.com/nakunaru/4560971

943 ではなく、IBM-943 と書かれておりました。
ないしは 数値だけの場合は1208を設定するようです。

的外れでしたら申し訳ありません。以上です。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。試してみた結果、環境変数コマンドともに変更してもUNKNOWNのままでした。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。

問題はPHP実行時に環境変数が組み込まれていないことだったので/etc/sysconfig/httpdにDB2CODEPAGE=943を追記することによって無事に接続できました。

ご協力感謝です。